# C++ Generate with a function from a pointer

Tags: c++, function, methods, stl

What's the best way to use a method from a pointer in `stl::generate`? An example:

```
std::vector<double> doSomethingToAVector(boost::shared_ptr<RandomGenerator> randomGen){
    std::vector<double> output(100);
    std::generate(output.begin(), output.end(), randomGen->returnANumber());
    return output;
}
```

`RandomGenerator` is just some arbitrary class with a method `returnANumber()` that returns an arbitrary double.

My compiler currently says

```
  called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer
    *__first = __gen();
```

Should I use `mem_fun` or other such magic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::bind()` to bind the implicit object parameter. For example:

```
std::generate(output.begin(), output.end(),
              std::bind(&RandomGenerator::returnANumber, randomGen));
```

I don't know if it works if `randomGen` is a `boost::shared_ptr<RandomGenerator>` but it certainly does work with a `std::shared_ptr<RandomGenerator>`. This assume the current C++ (i.e., the revision from 2011). I would expect that something similar work with Boost using C++03.

Comment: Hi. Yeah it seems that I need to `bind` it. Should it not be:

`std::bind(&RandomGenerator::returnANumber, randomGen, std::placeholders::_1)`

I'm reluctant to use C++11, as I know nothing of it yet and can't guarantee others will have it. Hmm.

Comment: @user2966558: `std::generate()` wants to use a nullary function object. Your expression would create a unary function, i.e., the algorithm would need to pass, at least, one argument but it doesn't pass any arguments to the generator function.
With respect to C++11, I think Boost has a similar `bind()` which is also works with pointer types as the first argument for member functions.

Comment: @user2966558 It does [work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/028215f13c7cee72) with `boost::bind`